# How to Verify assert throw exception for the return list function C#

Tags: c#, moq, assert, xunit

How do I use Assert (or other Test class) to verify that an exception has been thrown?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<HHABranchAggregatorConfigurationDto>> HHABranchAggregatorDetails(int HHA, int UserId, int HHA_Branch_ID)
{
    IEnumerable<HHABranchAggregatorConfigurationDto> hhabranchAggregatorsettingslists = new List<HHABranchAggregatorConfigurationDto>();

    try
    {
        var EVVVendorMasterList = await _UAEVVVendorMasterRepository._HHA_Schedule_GetUAEVVVendorMaster(HHA, UserId, "EvvVendorMasterID,VendorName,isPrimary");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e.Message);
    }

    return hhabranchAggregatorsettingslists;
}
```

Unit Test In this unit test trying to capture the null reference exception

```
[Fact]
public async Task Agency_Configuration_Should_Throw_Exception()
{
    //Arrange
    _UAEVVVendorMasterRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x._HHA_Schedule_GetUAEVVVendorMaster(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Throws<NullReferenceException>();
    //Act
    var hhabranchAggregatorsactuallist = await agencyConfigurations.HHABranchAggregatorDetails(1, 1, 3052);
    //Assert
    var ex = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => hhabranchAggregatorsactuallist);
}
```

But while doing this getting this error message needs suggestion

> Assert.Throws() Failure
> Expected: typeof(System.Exception)
> Actual:   (No exception was thrown)

Comment: Unit Test level changes Made
var ex = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<NullReferenceException>(async () => await agencyConfigurations.HHABranchAggregatorDetails(1, 1, 3052));

In HHABranchAggregatorDetails function in the catch function again throw the exception

So that unit testing is passed

Thanks to all the people who suggested and now got the expected result

Comment: It seems like what you want to be doing here is verifying that the logger is logging when an exception occurs, as opposed to that the application is throwing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ThrowsAsync` instead of `Throws`:

```
var ex = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await agencyConfigurations.HHABranchAggregatorDetails(1, 1, 3052));
```

Comment: this also tried but getting the same error message that Assert.Throws() Failure
Expected: typeof(System.Exception)
Actual: (No exception was thrown)

Comment: Instead Exception need to pass what type of exception we need to get here in my case it is NullRefernceException

Answer (score 0):

I assume because you catch the exception in the target method named "`HHABranchAggregatorDetails`", the Assert API doesn't notice it. You would need to either not catch or to rethrow it, I guess.

But of course its better in productive code to catch it ^^

Comment: catch I cant remove since we are capturing it has a log error message..any suggestion how to rethrow it again @lidqy

Comment: I just wanted to explain why the test doesn't 'see' any exception and the Assert fails.
Of course it's good that you catch the ex.
Since the line that throw seems to be:
"_UAEVVVendorMasterRepository._HHA_Schedule_GetUAEVVVendorMaster(...);"
you should simply unit-test this piece of code.
Then you'll likely get the exception you want to assert.